# How to make deleteAction to delete button in JPanel of other JPanel?

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a private JPanel :

`private JPanel bigPanel;`

Inside the bigPanel, I have another ten JPanel(panel_1D, panel_2D...). Each of them have a few buttons. Those buttons are added with deleteAction actionListener:

```
JPanel panel_1D = new JPanel();//Panel ONE

GridBagConstraints gbc_panel_1D = new GridBagConstraints();...
bigPanel.add(panel_1D, gbc_panel_1D);
GridBagLayout gbl_panel_1D = new GridBagLayout();...
panel_1D.setLayout(gbl_panel_1D);

          JButton button_2 = new JButton("ECG");
          GridBagConstraints gbc_button_2 = new GridBagConstraints();...
          button_2.addActionListener(deleteAction); 
          panel_1D.add(button_2, gbc_button_2);
          ...
```

I created a DELETE button in other panel(outside of the bigPanel):

```
JButton button_38 = new JButton("DELETE");
button_38.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delete any task by clicking it." , "INFO : 
", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);    
deleteNow = true;  
//allowOpen =false;             }
});
```

Then I set up deleteAction method:

```
private ActionListener deleteAction = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();
            if (deleteNow)
            {   //allowOpen=false;
                bigPanel.remove(button);
                bigPanel.revalidate();
                bigPanel.repaint();
                deleteNow = false;

            }
            else
            {
              System.out.println("My COMMAND IS : " + button.getActionCommand());
            }
        }
    };
```

Currently, if I RUN, I will click DELETE button. Then, a pop up message "Delete any task by clicking it." shown. So when I closed the pop up message, I clicked the button that I want to delete. Unfortunately, the button I clicked did not deleted.

**UPDATE:** After I change

```
bigPanel.remove(button);
bigPanel.revalidate();
bigPanel.repaint();
```

to

```
button.getParent().remove(button);
button.getParent().revalidate();
button.getParent().repaint();
```

I got warning in console :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at UI2$1.actionPerformed(UI2.java:128)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `remove()` on a container which contains coponent you want to remove, so instead:

```
bigPanel.remove(button);
```

you should call for example:

```
panel1_D.remove(button);
```

Because `buttons` are not in `bigPanel` directly (but in sub-panel). However, if you have a multiple panels with multiple buttons, the better solution would be:

```
button.getParent().remove(button);
```

`getParent()` method returns parent container for given component, so it should work with every `button` and you don't need to create methods for every group of buttons in different panels.

Comment: @m. cekiera Thank you. Actually I just need to do `button.getParent().remove(button);
              revalidate();
              repaint();`